# Push data to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

My client send me spreadsheet that contains all the transactions. Now I have to push those sheet data in Google Analytics, So How can I push those data in Google Analytics? Should I have to create a PHP Script that will read from spreadsheet and push to Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon how this data looks.  You should look into the [Measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en) which will allow you to send additional hits to Google analytics make sure that you check the [qt](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en#qt) parameter which will allow you to set the time that the hit came in.  There is no library for this you will have to code these calls yourself.

In the even that this is custom data then you could also [upload](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads) it directly.  You can use the Google api php client library for this to help you with your calls.

In either case yes your going to have to read the speedsheet yourself and then create the code in which ever language you choose to upload it.

Comment: Thank You DaImTo for answering my question. Can I use Data Import in Google Analytics? is it same functionalities?

Comment: Data imports is tricky i suggest you read up on the documentation.  Only you will know if this is something you can use as you know what this file contains for data you cant just upload a random file it needs to make sense in order to preform any analytics upon it.